# Increase default size for OUT VARCHAR2 variables in "Run PL/SQL" window

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

In the Oracle SQL Developer "Run PL/SQL" window, is there a way to increase the default variable size from `VARCHAR2(200)` to `VARCHAR2(4000)`?

For example, if you create a procedure like this:

```
create or replace procedure test_proc(p_out in out varchar2) is
begin
    p_out := lpad('A', 1000, 'A');
end;
/
```

And then right-click on the procedure and select "Run...":

[image]

The "Run PL/SQL" windows opens and creates an anonymous block for running the procedure and retrieving the output variables.

[image]

Unfortunately, the default size of `VARCHAR2(200)` is not large enough, and running the procedure generates the error "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small".

We can manually change the variables size from 200 to 4000, but it's annoying to have to do this every time, for every procedure. The window does temporarily remember the change, but it resets after the program is reopened.

And to make the problem even more annoying, the error actually gets generated *inside* the procedure. Which means that our logging system records these errors, and it's not trivial to separate them from legitimate errors.

Is there some way to change that default size? I don't see any option in the Preferences window in Version 21.4.1.349.

Comment: I don't think there is an option, but really the "Run" menu option is not intended to be used frequently - it's a way to quickly generate some sample code for running the procedure, but the idea is that you would customise the script to your requirements, and save it somewhere, e.g. in a script or compiled in a package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there's no option for this.

I'll investigate an ER to increase this to 4000.

As a workaround you could have scripts for testing your procedures, and then run those exactly as you please in the SQL worksheet using the Execute as Script (F5) button.

Comment: An ER would be great. Let me know if there's anything I can do to support or track such an enhancement. Thanks!